# Get Current Hls Stream Duration ExoPlayer

Tags: android, video-streaming, broadcast, exoplayer

I use ExoPlayer library for my Hls live broadcast. 
I have started a live stream with wirecast. Broadcast is in the second hour. But when test the stream with my android application, it always starts at 0. How to I get real duration on server with Exoplayer?

Comment: Did you find the answer? Please post the answer or solution link, if YES.